# Python: adding lists and accessing elements

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am new to Python and have a problem with lists. 
Namely, I'm asking user to fill 2 lists one for cars and one for the production year. Then I append both list to one.

```
enter code here
carYear = []
carYear.append(cars)
carYear.append(year)
```

I have 2 questions: 
a) is there an elegant way to print those lists, so the element car and year are listed close to each other (for ex: Porsche, 1998)? 
b) Is it possible to access first list (cars) from carYear list and print it?

Answer (score 2):

You can zip the two lists together like so:

```
cars = ["car1", "car2", "car3"]
years = ["2012", "2015", "2017"]
for c, y in zip(cars, years):
    print( "{0}, {1}".format(c, y) )
```

For each iteration you can print c and y. Which is the name and the year of the car.

Comment: @Ewa you are welcome. If you have 50 min, you can have a look at Raymond Hettinger(core python dev) talk:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&t=799s   He talks about izip at 21:50. Izip is better then zip (but you need to import itertools. That is why Idid not talk about it in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your data structure to use a `dict` instead of parallel `list` objects. Dictionaries (`dict`) are sometimes referred to as maps or associative arrays. They allow you to access data by associating it with a key value. The following example assumes that the elements of `cars` will serve as keys.

You can create a dictionary from your lists using `zip`, which transforms the given sequences into tuples.

```
>>> cars = ['civic', 'corvette', 'prius']
>>> years = ['2009', '1979', '2017']
>>> zip(cars, years)
[('civic', '2009'), ('corvette', '1979'), ('prius', '2017')]
```

A `list` of `tuple`s can be used to initialize a `dict` where first and second elements of each tuple are the key and value, respectively.

```
>>> carYear = dict(zip(cars, years))
>>> carYear
{'corvette': '1979', 'prius': '2017', 'civic': '2009'}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
>>> carYear['corvette']
'1979'
```

For printing the contents of `dict` objects, I like to use the `.items()` method which breaks things apart into tuples again. Observe:

```
for car, year in sorted(carYear.items()):
    print('Car: {} => {}'.format(car, year))
```

I am using `sorted` to ensure that output is consistent. Due to the implementation of `dict` objects, `.items()` will return data in random order each time you run. `sorted` addresses this problem, resulting in consistent output.

For more information about Python dictionaries see the Python docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can try [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (It should be faster than `dict`) e.g:

```py
from collections import namedtuple


cars = []
Car = namedtuple('Car', ['type', 'year'])
cars.append(Car('Porsche', '1998'))

for car in cars:
    print('{0}, {1}'.format(car.type, car.year))
```

But be aware, namedtuples are immutable. i.e. you cannot do `car.type = 'BMW'`